# what is the good way to sync and test the application server deployed on aws, using git?

Tags: amazon-web-services, synchronization

I am currently new to aws, usually I use putty as the console to debug the program, and use winscp to upload the new code to the server, but using winscp to update the server is kind of inefficient, I want to know if there is a easy, fast way allowing me to sync the code to the testing server deployed in the amazon instance.

something comes to my mind, is probably the git, I don't know how to do it in both sides, that once I update the repository locally to git server, the git server will automatically update the code to my testing server on aws

or if you have a better way than git

Answer (score 0):

Once you push the code to your git or github repo, you need to ssh to your server and pull the code. To achieve that, first generate the ssh key in your aws instance follow `[this][1]` instructions. Once your initial test says okay, then git clone your application to the desired path. Once you clone it update the app with the latest using git pull command.